# Why does pandas.read_excel() skip the first rows of a sheet?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have some data in an excel sheet shown in picture below that I want to read as dataframe using `pandas.read_excel`, however the function skips automatically the first 2 rows of the sheet as shown in image below. I can't figure out the problem source? and how can I solve it?

[image]

the following code is used:

```
import pandas as pd
import tkinter as Tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from tabulate import tabulate

print("Choose the desired Source file:")
Tk.Tk().withdraw()
path1 = askopenfilename() # the path to the file I want to use

source_workbook = pd.read_excel(path1, header=1, engine='openpyxl')
print(tabulate(source_workbook,headers='firstrow'))
```

The above code produces this result:

[image]

When I change the position of the excel table as shown below, the function produces the desired data frame shown in the image below also.

[image]

[image]

Comment: try header=0 while reading pd.read_excel()

Comment: header=0 by default gives the df column names.

Comment: [Please don't post pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341). Copy the text itself and use the formatting tools like [code formatting](/editing-help#code). And please provide a [mre]. Tkinter doesn't seem relevant, so try removing it from the equation. And is `tabulate` relevant? Try just `print(df)` and see if the same issue occurs. Also if it helps: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341)

Comment: I tried header=0 and I also removed the header, the same problem persists it started from the first row of data and took it as the column names for the data frame.

Comment: I was able to reproduce the issue. Remove `header=1`; it'll do `header=0` by default, which is what you want. Secondly, `headers='firstrow'` should be `headers='keys'`, or you could just `print(df)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to **wjandrea** for [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76542152/why-does-pandas-read-excel-skip-the-first-rows-of-a-sheet#comment134956670_76542152):

> Remove `header=1`; it'll do `header=0` by default, which is what you want. Secondly, `headers='firstrow'` should be `headers='keys'`, or you could just `print(df)` instead.